# does my ginger bug have mold?

Tags: yeast, carbonation, ginger-beer, ginger, mold

My ginger bug had been 3 days bubbling and fizzing, but now it's stopped bubbling and smells too much of fermented ginger, can somebody help me? please?
I need help urgently.

Comment: "_it's stopped bubbling and smells too much of fermented ginger_" That sounds like normal yeast operation. What ended up happening?

Answer (score 2):

Yeast *is* a mould (fungus), so you *want* your ginger bug to have mould.  If it has brightly coloured mould - black, red, yellow, discard it.  Generally yeast will stay in suspension for a while, before settling to the bottom, making a creamy-white layer.  While it's fermenting, yeast produces a lot of weird smells.

If it's stopped bubbling, the yeast has probably used-up all the sugar.  If you want to grow more yeast, let the yeast settle to the bottom, then decant the clear liquid on top, then add more pre-boiled 10% sugar-water.  (Or if your vessel is large enough, just add more without decanting.)

You could also put it in the fridge if you are not currently planning on using it.  This will slow down any fermentation activity.